# Git Insert Delete Graph

Tags: perl, git, data-visualization, svg

I attempted to recreate the GitHub code frequency graph ([example](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/graphs/code-frequency)) with a daily granularity using Perl and `git log`. How did I do, and what improvements can I make? I know that I should try to reduce the frequency of keys on the x-axis, but I have no idea how to do that and maintain scale.

[image: Example of the output]

It should be noted that the default application for open SVG files should be set to a browser of some sort.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# Henry J Schmale
# November 4, 2015
#
# Creates an insertion and delation graph per day graph for a git repo. It
# outputs an svg of the graph on standard output.
#
# This script can take the name of a directory to produce the graph for
# that directory if no param is given, then it does it in the current
# directory. 
#
# Requires SVG::TT:Graph::Line

use strict;
use warnings;

# Get the path to the stylesheet first
use File::Spec;
use File::Basename;
my $graphsty = dirname(File::Spec->rel2abs(__FILE__)) . '/svg-graph-ss.css';

# CD into the directory specified if specified 
if(-e $ARGV[0] and -d $ARGV[0]){
    chdir $ARGV[0];
}

# Indexed by date
my %commits;

# get the git log and preprocess it
my $gitlogOutput = qx(git log --numstat --pretty="%H %aI" | grep -v '^\$');


my @lines = split /\n/, $gitlogOutput;
my $date;
my $hash;
foreach (@lines) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /\s+/;
    # Length of sha1sum
    if(length($fields[0]) > 39){
        $hash = $fields[0];
        $date = substr($fields[1], 0, 10);
    }else{
        $commits{$date}->{ins} += $fields[0];
        $commits{$date}->{del} += $fields[1];
    }
}


use DateTime;
use Date::Parse;
use Data::Dumper;

my $firstDate = getDateTime(((sort keys %commits)[0]));
my $lastDate  = getDateTime(((sort keys %commits)[-1]));
# print "$firstDate\t".((sort keys %commits)[0])."\n";
# print "$lastDate\t".((sort keys %commits)[-1])."\n";

# print (scalar keys %commits)."\n";
while($firstDate->add(days => 1) < $lastDate){
    my $key = $firstDate->ymd('-');
    if(!defined $commits{$key}){
        $commits{$key}->{ins} = 0;
        $commits{$key}->{del} = 0;
    }
}
# print scalar keys %commits;
# print "\n";

# Prepare data for graphing by converting them to arrays
my (@key, @ins, @del, @net);
my $i = 0;
foreach (sort keys %commits){
    $key[$i] = $_;
    $ins[$i] = $commits{$_}{ins};
    # del must be negitive in order for graph to look right, with delations
    # being below the x axis.
    $del[$i] = -$commits{$_}{del};
    $net[$i] = $commits{$_}{ins} - $commits{$_}{del};
    # printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $_, $ins[$i], $del[$i], $net[$i]);
    $i++;
}

# Get the max value in the data sets
my @allpoints;
my ($min, $max);
push @allpoints, @ins;
push @allpoints, @del;
push @allpoints, @net;
for(@allpoints){
    $min = $_ if !$min || $_ < $min;
    $max = $_ if !$max || $_ > $max;
}

# Graph it
use SVG::TT::Graph::Line;

my $graph = SVG::TT::Graph::Line->new({
        width => 1200,
        height => 800,
        fields => \@key,
        scale_integers => 1,
        rotate_x_labels => 1,
        show_data_values => 0,
        show_data_points => 0,
        min_scale_value => $min,
        max_scale_value => $max,
        style_sheet => $graphsty,
    });
# Add the data
$graph->add_data({
        'data' => \@ins,
        title => 'Inserts Per Day'
    });
$graph->add_data({
        'data' => \@del,
        title => 'Deletions Per Day'
    });
$graph->add_data({
        'data' => \@net,
        title => 'Net Insert/Del Per Day'
    });

# Print file 
my $filepath = '/tmp/gitGraph.svg';
open my $FD,'>',$filepath or die $!;
print $FD $graph->burn();
close $FD;

# Open it up in the browser or prefered method for opening the file
$filepath = 'file://'.$filepath;
qx(xdg-open $filepath);

sub getDateTime {
    my ($ss,$mm,$hh,$day,$month,$year,$zone) = strptime($_[0]);
    # print "\t$_[0]\n";
    return DateTime->new(
        day => $day,
        month => $month + 1,
        # We have to add 1900 here inorder to make the date format work
        year  => ($year + 1900)
    );
}
```

Comment: Empty string for every odd element on X axis?

Comment: @mpapec It only happens on the first run for a repository, or if you have dozens of branches.

Comment: Just a style thing, but the `use SVG::TT::Graph::Line;` should be at the top. So should the other `use` statements that are in the middle. They will all be loaded at compile time anyway.

Answer (score 4):

A simple thing to add would be a Logarithmic Y-scaling function, so that significant bursts in either losses or gains don't get over-exaggerated perceptually. Essentially you want 100-commit days to only take up at most, 10x as much space as 1 commit days, so "low activity" wavering is still visible.

I'd also suggest breaking windows of about 7 days into single data points, by aggregating them and representing them as 5 lines each:

- Max number of commits per day in 7-day-range,
- Upper Quartile number of commits per day in 7-day-range
- Median number of commits per day ...
- Lower Quartile ....
- Min...

And then render it with some shades like this ( half-assed mockup )

[image]

With this, you could afford to *narrow* the sample window to "per hour" say, but still represent the data accumulated in terms of weeks, so you'd have "max commits/hour this week", "min commits/hour this week", etc, all represented in a single vertical column.

Comment: IMO a CR post almost always should include some code (or at least a reference to original code) otherwise it's more about UX (which is good and desiderable but maybe off-topic)

Comment: I mostly agree. But here it's not entirely obvious what the author is asking for, seems like they're wanting both. The code ... is ... well, more scary than I can begin to start on :/

Answer (score 4):

### Overview

It is great that you:

- Used `strict` and `warnings`
- Leveraged other people's code by using the CPAN modules
- Used comments at the top of the file to describe the code

Here are some adjustments for you to consider, mainly for coding style.

### Warning

I get a warning if I don't specify a directory on the command line.
The `-e` file test isn't doing what you expect.  It does not check
if the argument was passed in.  This is one way to do it:

```
# If a directory is specified on the command line, change into it
chdir $ARGV[0] if $ARGV[0] and -d $ARGV[0];
```

### Modules

It is customary to place all the `use` statements together at the top
of the file:

Since this is not used, just delete the line:

```
use Data::Dumper;
```

### Namespace

It is best to import only what is needed to avoid namespace pollution.
For example, change:

```
use File::Basename;
```

to:

```
use File::Basename qw(dirname);
```

These are all the `use` statements:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec           qw();
use File::Basename       qw(dirname);
use DateTime             qw();
use Date::Parse          qw(strptime);
use SVG::TT::Graph::Line qw();
```

---

Provide more debugging information to the user (the file name) if `open`
fails.  Change:

```
open my $FD,'>',$filepath or die $!;
```

to:

```
open my $FD, '>', $filepath or die "$filepath $!";
```

---

There is no need for the following scalar variable and for `split`:

```
my $gitlogOutput = qx(git log --numstat --pretty="%H %aI" | grep -v '^\$');
my @lines = split /\n/, $gitlogOutput;
```

Simplified as:

```
my @lines = qx(git log --numstat --pretty="%H %aI" | grep -v '^\$');
```

---

The `$hash` variable is declared and set, but it is never read.  It can
be deleted.

---

Since you don't use the `@allpoints` array anywhere else, you can
get rid of the variable and simplify all these lines:

```
my @allpoints;
push @allpoints, @ins;
push @allpoints, @del;
push @allpoints, @net;
for(@allpoints){
```

as:

```
for (@ins, @del, @net) {
```

---

Since the "quote executable" operator interpolates variables,
you can simplify these 2 lines:

```
$filepath = 'file://'.$filepath;
qx(xdg-open $filepath);
```

as:

```
qx(xdg-open file://$filepath);
```

---

There is no need for the single quotes around the `data` key:

```
$graph->add_data({
        'data' => \@ins,
        title => 'Inserts Per Day'
```

It would be more consistent to omit them as you did for the `title` key:

```
$graph->add_data({
        data  => \@ins,
        title => 'Inserts Per Day'
```

---

Since `foreach` is identical to `for`, and you already use `for`
elsewhere in the code, you should just use `for` everywhere.